# When deploying an EAR into WebSphere, what's the cause of a "duplicate entry" SaveFailureException?

Tags: jakarta-ee, build, websphere

When attempting to install the EAR, the following exception results:

```
Caught Exception installing ApplicationName  
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: AppDeploymentException: []  
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: META-INF/application.xml  
META-INF/application.xml  
duplicate entry: META-INF/application.xml  
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: META-INF/application.xml
```

Needless to say, the EAR file does not have two application.xml files within it, so I can't explain the "duplicate entry" error.  Is this exception familiar to anyone?  How is it resolved?

Comment: I would guess either a product defect or the EAR is strangely packaged.  What is the output of unzip -l on the EAR?

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to open/explore the ear with 7-zip and make sure there are not two application.xml files at the META-INF level. Zip *will* create duplicate entries for files under many conditions, particularly if you are zipping source files together from multiple directories.  We just had this exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this today..

`Ear.setAppXml()`: `ear` task in ant, are putting the duplicate entry of `META-INF/application.xml`, while re-packing an `EAR` (from the same location where its exploded).

`setAppXml()`: `appxml` attribute in `ear` task, needed a path to the `application.xml` file. If the path is specified as `{exploded.dir}/META-INF/application.xml`, then it puts two entries.

Solution:

```
Copy the META-INF/application.xml to some /tmp/app.xml
Pass "/tmp/app.xml" for setAppXml() / "appxml" in ear task
Delete the entry: {exploded.dir}/META-INF/application.xml
Pack the EAR now.
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is another application with the same name already deployed onto that server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you have another JAR file, located inside the EAR's root, that has a `META-INF/application.xml` in it.

Sounds bizarre? I know, but I've seen this happen before (developers included EAR files within EAR files).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out to be a space issue on the server from which I was performing the deploy.  The target had plenty of space, the server that was doing the deploy was completely out.