# unable to deploy EAR using jython in WAS 8.0 commadline

Tags: java, solaris, jython, ear, websphere-8

I have installed WAS 8.0 in solaris 11 server. I'm trying to deploy Application EAR in WAS using jython script.

**Jython Script: /home/deploy.py**

```
earLoc='/home/artifacts/Statement-bva-application.ear'

appName='Statement-bva'

cellName=AdminControl.getCell()

nodeName=AdminControl.getNode()

appManager=AdminControl.queryNames('cell='+cellName+',node='+nodeName+',type=ApplicationManager,process=server1,*')

print appManager

#AdminControl.invoke(appManager , 'stopApplication',appName)

print AdminApp.uninstall(appName)

AdminConfig.save()

print AdminApp.install(earLoc)

AdminConfig.save()

AdminControl.invoke(appManager , 'startApplication',appName)
```

**WAS command :**

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /home/deploy.py
```

But it failed to install the EAR through jython script

```
 WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/home/deploy.py"; 

    exception information: 

    com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: 

    com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: 

    [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: META-INF/application.xml] 

    org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: 

    org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: META-INF/application.xml
```

I can able to install the application through WAS admin console. It fails via jython script.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716861/when-deploying-an-ear-into-websphere-whats-the-cause-of-a-duplicate-entry-sa and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939529/websphere-8-5-root-exception-is-org-eclipse-jst-j2ee-commonarchivecore-internal

Comment: i have checked those related questions. There is no duplicate application.xml in my EAR and no comments. We able to install through WAS admin Console, it fails only through jython script. It Java version will be the issue?

Comment: It's possible the Java version could be an issue. Is there more than one version of Java installed?  Which JVM install is WebSphere using?  Is the same JVM used by your jython script?

Comment: java installed in the solaris environment is 1.80_05.  How to check the JVM version used by WAS. I checked the java version in /opt/IBM/WebSpere/AppServer/java/bin/java -version, it shows 1.6.0_105

Comment: I would check `PROFILE_HOME/logs/wsadmin.traceout`.  That file typically contains multiple exception stack traces when deployment fails, and one of them typically gives a better hint about what might be wrong.

Comment: Assuming the JVM used by WAS is 1.6.0_105, are you building your EAR so it's compatible with Java 1.6?

Comment: Yes.. EAR is compactible